# How to read a size of area "Grid"? or how to get data from xaml into C++/CX code?

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am using dynamic marking of area "Grid"

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--This Grid-->
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Name="gridImage" SizeChanged="gridImage_SizeChanged">
        <Image Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>     

</Grid>
```

In my code I am drawing image pixel-by-pixel depending on size of "Grid" which contains this image. How can I read the size of "Grid" area in code?

Properties gridImage->Width and gridImage->Height  lets me set values but not get them.

```
gridImage->Width = 100;//OK
gridImage->Height = 100;//OK

int width = gridImage->Width;//return -2 147 483 648
int height = gridImage->Height;//return -2 147 483 648
```

If I use  SizeChanged event for Grid area then I can read size by using this code

```
void MainPage::gridImage_SizeChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::SizeChangedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Size size = e->NewSize;
    int width = size.Width;//OK
    int height= size.Height;//OK
}
```

But this event becomes available only after changing of image object, it means that that becomes available after then I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth) and [ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) properties to get the actual width and height in pixels, respectively. Unlike the Height, Width, MinHeight, MinWidth, MaxHeight and MaxWidth, they actually contain the height and width.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
That is what I was looking for.
And I understood what was my mistake.
I am drawing by "OnNavigatedTo" function but dynamic marking of area "Grid" becomes after "OnNavigatedTo".